# If I decide to stick with a non-LTS version, even after its support ends, will it seriously affect me?

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, lts

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.10, and I'm happy with it just the way it is. A few minor upgrades are always welcome, but I can certainly live without them. I'm one of those few people who actually likes Unity 7, and switching back to GNOME is something that I find unacceptable. I've decided to upgrade my system to 17.04 and keep it at that.

My concern is that will my workflow be affected by this? For example, say a new version of Python or JDK or Android Studio arrives 2 years later. Will I be able to install and use it (preferably via PPA), or would I have to give up on that installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Is it a good idea? No, and just for one reason: security.

Unity 7 will still be available in 18.04. Just not as the default but you can install Unity as a desktop if you want.

> Will I be able to install and use it (preferably via PPA), or would I have to give up on that installation?

What PPA do you expect to install it from? Because there will not be one for 17.04. From Gnome 3 repositories? That could potentially turn your system into gnome 3 when you upgrade with one of these active.

> I'm one of those few people who actually likes Unity 7

Me too. Installing a system with U7 took me 25 minutes to get to what I wanted. I have made the switch to Gnome 3 and those shell extensions suck. Every day the one for "applications" resets itself to "off". I had to create a startup application to get native scrolling working how I want it but that one too gets killed randomly. Besides that it takes me 2.5 hours to get it to what I want and even then it is not as useful as U7.

I am going to try Budgie en KDE soon if G3 keeps annoying me.

Comment: Honestly (and it may sound childish), I love my DE. I mean, I don't like the way "out-of-the-box" Unity looks, but after a one-time 1.5 hours customization, and I'm in love with it. If I can get Unity to work on 18.10, that would be awesome. I'd upgrade in a heartbeat. Can you link the tutorial?

Comment: There is no 18.04 or 18.10 yet. And Unity 7 will be the DE in 17.04 and 17.10. In 18.04 you can expect something like `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to install U7 (as it would do now).